# What is the difference between @nestjs/websockets and @nestjs/platform-socket.io packages in NestJS

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I have researched this topic online and have found nearly-similar questions to this - But, I need to know why in NestJS we have to use two packages to implement WebSocket communication.

The two packages are,

- @nestjs/websockets
- @nestjs/platform-socket.io

I understand that WebSocket is the protocol and Socket.IO is a library which has both server and client versions of it.

In the gateway file of NestJS when implementing a WebSocket connection, one has to write code similar to below.

```js
import {
  ConnectedSocket,
  MessageBody,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';

import { Server } from 'socket.io';
```

My questions,

1. What is the difference between `WebSocketServer` and `Server` here?
2. Why do we import `Server` from `socket.io` and not `@nestjs/platform-socket.io`?
3. How do you describe the purpose of using each of these packages in a single sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@nestjs/websockets` is the base package that makes websocket integration possible in NestJS. `@nestjs/platform-socket.io` is the specific package for `socket.io` integration, rather than something like `@nestjs/platform-ws` which is for the `ws` package.

`WebsocketServer` is the decorator to tell Nest to inject the websocket server, `Server` is the socket.io *type* for the server.

We import `Socket` from `socket.io` because `@nestjs/platform-socket.io` is really just for the websocket adapter that plugs into Nest's platform.

Single sentences:

- `@nestjs/websockets`: allows for websocket communication via a websocket adapter
- `@nestjs/platform-socket.io`: socket.io websocket adapter to allow for socket.io websocket communication with the server
- `socket.io`: a websocket implementation and engine that is usable with and without NestJS

Comment: I'm super thankful for this answer. Probably the fastest and one of the best answers I have received. This cleared a lot for me. Thanks @Jay!